# Using Excel Formulas in JavaScript code outside of excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I want to call excel's GammaDist and Gammaln functions in one of my JavaScript/JQuery code. I have the values of x, alpha and beta and in output need whatever excel formula gives.

I was trying to get some API which I can call in my js code to call this function but was not able to find anything

QQ = 1 - Application.WorksheetFunction.GammaDist(1, z + 1, 1 / a, True)

need to calculate this equation in javascript/JQuery

Comment: Look for a statistics library using Google

Comment: I am trying to find it out but was unable to get any...

Comment: I Googled "javascript gamma distribution" and the second result looks like an excellent option.

Comment: That's not what excel does...excels version of gammadist take 4 arguments and uses a different algorithm

Comment: Right, I didn't mean to imply that there was something you could swap in and call in the exact same fashion. Don't expect that.